# Android How to show circular shadow using ViewOutlineProvider?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view for which I want to show circular shadow using ViewOutlineProvider supported in API 21+. While setting up the roundRect for outline. I am always getting the shadow effect like below where the rectangle has somehow got converted into a polygon.

**Custom View With Shadow**

[image: Custom View With Shadow]

My ViewOutlineProvider looks like this

```
private class OutlineProvider extends ViewOutlineProvider {

    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        outline.setRoundRect(rect, rect.width()/2f);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this without margin:

```
setClipToOutline(true);
setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), cornerSize);
    }
});
```

Otherwise:

```
setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
  @Override
  public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    int leftMargin = layoutParams.leftMargin;
    int topMargin = layoutParams.topMargin;
    rect.set(leftMargin, topMargin, rect.right - rect.left - leftMargin, rect.bottom - rect.top - topMargin);
    outline.setRoundRect(rect, ...);
    view.setClipToOutline(true);
  }
});
```

and add this View into a ViewGroup as its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `setOutlineProvider` method of the view.

```
private class OutlineProvider extends ViewOutlineProvider {    
    @Override
    public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        outline.setRoundRect(rect, rect.width()/2f);
        view.setOutlineProvider(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an OutlineProvider that extends the ViewOutlineProvider, which is to be set within the customView and not within itself.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, my calculation of rectangle bounds was wrong due to which the shadow was cast that way. The bounds of the rectangle should depend on the content that is drawn and not on the whole view bounds, so miscalculation will cast poor shadows.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for outline is absolutely correct, but I guess it is a bug in android code when you use OutlineProvider with clip-path for drawable it shows strange behavior for certain condition like the one you are facing, To make it more clear I am showing a demo using the same code as yours with a different conditions

**First image**: CustomImageView with [Image with shadow]
add 2 round rectangle in clipping path (1 with a round rectangle with radius, 2 with round rectangle but no 0 radius)

**Second image**: CustomImageView with [Image with shadow]
All things are the same as the First ImageView Code except its height and width are same as you can see how strange it behave in this condition

**Third image**: CustomImageView with [Image with shadow]
All things are the same as the Second ImageView Code except here I didn't use ViewOutlineProvider and you can see It is showing what we are excepting

**Fourth image**: CustomImageView with [Image with shadow]
Here just use one round rectangle with and every this is working as I excepted

So, If I conclude this, I think you should reconsider your image clipping logic, hope it will resolve your issue.

[image: Valid XHTML]